# Dressing an operator by Wilson line in Quantum Electrodynamic

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, gauge-theory, commutator, wilson-loop

I am reading a paper [arXiv:1507.07921](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07921) which introduce gravitational dressing. The paper compare it to dressing in QED.

Consider the scalar QED lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}(F^{\mu\nu})^2-|D_\mu\phi|^2-m^2|\phi|^2$$
$\phi$ is not invariant under
$$\begin{aligned} A_\mu\quad&\to\quad A_\mu-\partial_\mu\Lambda(x)\\ \phi(x)\quad&\to\quad e^{-iq\Lambda(x)}\phi(x).\end{aligned}$$
We can dress $\phi(x)$ to make it invariant. Define
$$\Phi(x)=V(x)\phi(x),$$ with $V$ transform as $V\to e^{iq\Lambda(x)}$, $\Phi$ is invariant under the transform.

One of the way of dressing is by Wilson line, which we define (along $z$ direction) $\Phi(x)=\phi(x)e^{iq\int ds A_z(x+s\hat z)}$.

We have the commutation relationship of $$[E^z, \Phi(x)].$$ (Equation (9) in [arXiv:1507.07921](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07921).)

My question is, what is the meaning of this commutator? The paper says when we are creating a particle by acting $\Phi$, we also increase the electric field. To my understanding, when creating a particle, we act $\Phi$ on $|0\rangle$, i.e. $\Phi|0\rangle=\phi e^{iq\int ds A_z(x+s\hat z)}|0\rangle$. We don't need a commutator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any state $|\Psi\rangle$ upon proper normalization $\Phi|\Psi\rangle$ is the state after adding (removing) one particle, we have $\langle \Psi\Phi^\dagger |E_z\Phi|\Psi\rangle = \langle \Psi\Phi^\dagger |\Phi E_z|\Psi\rangle + \langle \Psi\Phi^\dagger |[E_z,\Phi]|\Psi\rangle$, while the first term $\sim \langle \Psi|E_z|\Psi\rangle$ and when $[Ez,\Phi]\sim g\Phi$ (also Equation (9) in arXiv:1507.07921.) the second term $\sim g$.Thus, the commutator means the electric field change after adding (removing) one particle.